# Hi, I am new to coding and currently building an MVC and I have a CS0161 ERROR and I cant seem to fix it. Any help appreciated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
namespace Funko626.Controllers
{
    public class FunkoController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IFunkoRepository _funkoRepository;
        private readonly IBrandRepository _brandRepository;

        public FunkoController(IFunkoRepository funkoRepository, IBrandRepository brandRepository)
        {
         _funkoRepository = funkoRepository;
         _brandRepository = brandRepository;
        }

        public ViewResult List()
        {
            FunkoListViewModel funkoListViewModel = new()
            {
                Funkos = _funkoRepository.AllFunkos,

                CurrentBrand = " "
            };
            return View(funkoListViewModel);
        }
       //I think it's this part of the code with 'int id' but cant be sure.
        public IActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var funko = _funkoRepository.GetFunkoById(id);
            if(funko == null)
                return NotFound();
        }

    }
}
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0161  'FunkoController.Details(int)': not all code paths return
> a
> value Funko626    C:\Users\bidde\source\repos\Funko626\Controllers\FunkoController.cs 29  Active

Comment: Your `Details()` method doesn't return anything if `funko` is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CS0161](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0161) is about the most obvious error you'll get in programming. It says

> A method that returns a value must have a return statement in all code paths

Which means, in English, that if your method returns something then every code path must return that thing

So what's wrong here:

```
public IActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var funko = _funkoRepository.GetFunkoById(id);
    if(funko == null)
         return NotFound();
}
```

if `funko` is *NOT* null then nothing is returned. Fix it by returning something below the `if` condition. Usually this might look something like:

```
public IActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var funko = _funkoRepository.GetFunkoById(id);
    if(funko == null)
         return NotFound();

    // we found a funko!
    return Ok(funko);
}
```